# Why cannot I pass a c array to a function which expects memory view in nogil content?

Tags: cython

```
cdef double testB(double[:] x) nogil:
    return x[0]

def test():
    cdef double xx[2]
        with nogil:
            testB(xx)

# compiler error: Operation not allowed without gil
```

If with gil, it works fine.

Is it because that when pass in an c array, it creates a memory view and such creation action actually requires gil? So the memory view is not completely a c object?

#### Update

```
%%cython --annotate
cimport cython

cdef double testA(double[:] x) nogil:
    return x[0]

cpdef myf():
    cdef double pd[8]
    cdef double[:] x = pd
    testA(x)
```

`cdef double[:] x = pd` is compiled to:

```
  __pyx_t_3 = __pyx_format_from_typeinfo(&__Pyx_TypeInfo_double);
  __pyx_t_2 = Py_BuildValue((char*) "("  __PYX_BUILD_PY_SSIZE_T  ")", ((Py_ssize_t)8));
  if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_3 || !__pyx_t_2 || !PyBytes_AsString(__pyx_t_3))) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 8; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
  __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_3);
  __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_2);
  __pyx_t_1 = __pyx_array_new(__pyx_t_2, sizeof(double), PyBytes_AS_STRING(__pyx_t_3), (char *) "fortran", (char *) __pyx_v_pd);
  if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 8; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
  __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_1);
  __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_2); __pyx_t_2 = 0;
  __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_3); __pyx_t_3 = 0;
  __pyx_t_4 = __Pyx_PyObject_to_MemoryviewSlice_ds_double(((PyObject *)__pyx_t_1));
  if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_4.memview)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 8; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
  __Pyx_DECREF(((PyObject *)__pyx_t_1)); __pyx_t_1 = 0;
  __pyx_v_x = __pyx_t_4;
  __pyx_t_4.memview = NULL;
  __pyx_t_4.data = NULL;
```

There exists `__Pyx_PyObject_to_MemoryviewSlice_ds_double`. So it seems when binding a memory view it does require gil.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a numpy array, as your cdef double[:] declaration gets wrapped by a Python object, and its use is restricted without gil. You can see it by trying to slice a `double[:]`

```
def test()
    cdef double[:] asd
    with nogil:
        asd[:1]
```

Your output will be:

```
  with nogil:
            asd[:1]
              ^
    ------------------------------------------------------------

prueba.pyx:16:11: Slicing Python object not allowed without gil
```

Using a numpy array would compile; numpy uses Python buffer protocole, and is smoothly integrated with Cython (a Google Summercamp project was financed for this). So no wrapping conflict arises inside the def:

```
import numpy as np

    cdef double testA(double[:] x) nogil:
        return x[0]

    cpdef test():
        xx = np.zeros(2, dtype = 'double')
        with nogil:
            a = testB(xx)
        print(a)
```

This will build your module with test() on it. But it crashes, and in an ugly way (at least with mi PC):

```
Process Python segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

If I may insist with my (now deleted) previous answer, in my own experience, when dealing with Cython memoryviews and C arrays, passing pointers works just like one would expect in C. And most wrapping is avoided (actually, you are writing the code passing exactly the directions you want, thus making unnecesary wrapping). This compiles and functions as expected:

```
cdef double testB(double* x) nogil:
    return x[0]

def test():
    cdef double asd[2]
    asd[0] = 1
    asd[1] = 2
    with nogil:
        a = testB(asd)
    print(a)
```

And, after compilig:

```
In [5]: import prueba

In [6]: prueba.test()
1.0
```

Memoryviews are not, by themselves, Python objects, but they can be wrapped in one. I am not a proficient Cython programmer, so sometimes I get unexpected wrappings or code that remains at Python level when I supposed it would be at C. Trial and error got me to the pointer strategy.